# 2 threads handling sockets with weird behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, synchronous

I just finished my C# proxy containing 2 sockets (one client-socket receiving data from a certain client, one server-socket receiving data from a certain server).

**- Method I)**

The **fully working** receive/send procedure from a previous early-alpha version uses the following memory eating, quick and dirty method **I won't implement again:**

```
            while (true)
            {
                if (ClientSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    // Received data from the game client
                    byte[] buf = new byte[ClientSocket.Available];
                    ClientSocket.Receive(buf);
                    Packet p = new Packet(buf);
                    Logger.Log(p.ID, LogType.PACKET);
                    // Forward re-encrypted data back to the official server
                    ServerSocket.Send(p.Encrypt());
                }

                if (ServerSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    // Received Data from the official server
                    byte[] buf = new byte[ServerSocket.Available];
                    ServerSocket.Receive(buf);
                    Packet p = new Packet(buf);
                    Logger.Log(p.ID, LogType.PACKET);
                    // Forward re-encrypted data back to the game client
                    ClientSocket.Send(p.Encrypt());
                }
            }
```

**- Method II)**

The **not working** receive/send procedure from the actual version uses the following memory friendly method split into 2 threads:

```
class ClientReceiveThread
{
    public Thread T { get; set; }
    public ClientReceiveThread(Socket ClientSocket, Socket ServerSocket)
    {
        T = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {               
                while (ClientSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    // Received data from the game client
                    byte[] buf = new byte[ClientSocket.Available];
                    ClientSocket.Receive(buf);
                    Packet p = new Packet(buf);
                    Logger.Log(p.ID, LogType.PACKET);
                    // Forward re-encrypted data back to the official server
                    ServerSocket.Send(p.Encrypt());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Handle(e);
            }
        });
        T.Start();
    }
}

class ServerReceiveThread
{
    public Thread T { get; set; }
    public ServerReceiveThread(Socket ClientSocket, Socket ServerSocket)
    {
        T = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                while (ServerSocket.Available > 0)
                {
                    // Received Data from the official server
                    byte[] buf = new byte[ServerSocket.Available];
                    ServerSocket.Receive(buf);
                    Packet p = new Packet(buf);
                    Logger.Log(p.ID, LogType.PACKET);
                    // Forward re-encrypted data back to the game client
                    ClientSocket.Send(p.Encrypt());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Handle(e);
            }
        });
        T.Start();
    }
}
```

Method I) does insofar work that both Client- and Serversockets receive data, while method II) only receives data from the ClientReceiveThread.
Why does ServerReceiveThread in method II) not receive data? It's basically the same code as in the `while(true)` loop, only ported to a seperate thread.

Any suggestions or answers are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question. Take a look into the Task Parallel Library in place of threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by avoiding the "Available" property:

```
class ClientReceiveThread
{
    public Thread T { get; set; }
    public ClientReceiveThread(Socket ClientSocket, Socket ServerSocket)
    {
        T = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {               
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                while (ClientSocket.Receive(buf) > 0)
                {
                    // Received data from the game client
                    Packet p = new Packet(buf);
                    Logger.Log(p.ID, LogType.PACKET);
                    // Forward re-encrypted data back to the official server
                    ServerSocket.Send(p.Encrypt());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Handle(e);
            }
        });
        T.Start();
    }
}

class ServerReceiveThread
{
    public Thread T { get; set; }
    public ServerReceiveThread(Socket ClientSocket, Socket ServerSocket)
    {
        T = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                while (ServerSocket.Receive(buf) > 0)
                {
                    // Received Data from the official server
                    Packet p = new Packet(buf);
                    Logger.Log(p.ID, LogType.PACKET);
                    // Forward re-encrypted data back to the game client
                    ClientSocket.Send(p.Encrypt());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionHandler.Handle(e);
            }
        });
        T.Start();
    }
}
```